# Should Java class name duplicate package name?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I'm thinking about what is the best practice in Java for the following case:

I have a logic in my program that I want to put in a separate package.

For example (my current case), it is a logic that will collect some statistics and later send them to server). So my package under my project **com.example.project** will be named **com.example.project.statistics**.

There will be some classes inside the package, in this case StatisticsDispatcher (basically container and manager for events) and StatisticsEvent (event that should be calculated into statistics).

The question is, what naming convention should I use? I see two options:

1. **StatisticsDispatcher** and **StatisticsEvent** like mentioned above. The class name makes clear what the class does, but is a bit verbose in the absolute name, like com.example.project.statistics.StatisticsEvent.
2. **Dispatcher** and **Event**. It is shorter and the purpose of the class is clear from its absolute name, like com.example.project.statistics.Dispatcher , but later on in the code these names can be ambiguous with other packages' classes and even if not, when I import these classes in the beginning of a file, class names like "Dispatcher" and "Event" are very general and in the middle of a file it will not be evident what are they related to.

I haven't found any mention about this when googling java package and class naming conventions. I'm afraid the first option will be correct, but I really don't like the verbosity in the package name and the class name, so I want to ask you, other programmers, how do you solve such cases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say that example 1 is "a bit ambiguous" but the opposite is true. That example is LESS ambiguous than example 2 for exactly the reasons you raise in your comments on the second choice.

Comment: Redundancy is sometimes a *good thing*.

Comment: I feel bad about option 1) too. This is just a sad fact about the Java language, considering that some other languages can import a namespace by only importing the identifier of the namespace and enforce the qualification of the identifier when referencing the symbols under that namespace. (e.g., in Ruby, after `include Example::Project`, you can then do `Statistics::Event` to reference the Event class)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would prefer to be explicit (and perhaps verbose) to being concise (and perhaps ambiguous).

Your example re. `Dispatcher` / `Event` is a good one. If you're unlucky, you'll end up having to fully qualify each occurrence of these to resolve any ambiguities.

In such a scenario you'll end up either with a lot of verbose code, or restructuring your code such that conflicting classes don't co-exist (conflicts may actually act as an indicator that unrelated entities are co-existing, but that's another discussion)

Comment: Thanks. All the answers here say basically this, so I will stay with it. I'll just have to accept the fact that the word "statistics" is used twice in absolute name.

Comment: Some JVM languages (I'm thinking of Scala in particular) will allow you to rename the class in the import e.g. import com.x.y.statistics.Event => StatisticsEvent if you're encountering problems. It's merely a directive for the compiler

Answer (score 5):

I'll definitely go for the first one, that is, StatisticsDispatcher and StatisticsEvent because the words Dispatcher and Event used alone could mean a lot of things (particularly in Java EE).

Answer (score 4):

I would also definitely go for the less ambiguous names. Using any names which might conflict with other packages also:

- causes problems for the human reader of the code. If I see "Event" then I may assume it's a common Java library  and the only way to resolve this is to read back to the `import` statement.
- causes problems for IDEs. Eclipse, for example, sometimes "helpfully" guesses the most likely package. List, Element, Attribute, etc. may be imported from packages you never even knew existed! And it can be a surprising amount of wasted time to debug this.